# Problems with inequality in $\mathbb{C}^{n}$

Tags: complex-analysis, inequality

Suppose I have $x\in\mathbb{C}^{n}$ such that $x\in\overline{B}_{2}(\xi,r):=\{x\in\mathbb{C}^{n}: ||x-\xi||_{2}\leq r\}$, where $||\cdot||_{2}$ is the $2$-norm in $\mathbb{C}^{n}$, defined as follows:
$$
||(x_{1},...,x_{n})||_{2}:=\left(|x_{1}|^{2}+...+|x_{n}|^{2}\right)^{\frac{1}{2}}, \forall (x_{1},...,x_{n})\in\mathbb{C}^{n}.
$$
Now, let $||x||_{2}^{\mathbb{P}}:=\left(||x||_{2}^{2}+1\right)^{\frac{1}{2}}$, $\forall x\in\mathbb{C}^{n}$. Let $\xi\in\mathbb{C}^{n}$ such that $||\xi||_{2}=r>0$, and let $C>0$ be a constant. I am trying to prove that:
$$
\forall x\in \overline{B}_{2}(\xi,r), \left(||x||_{2}^{\mathbb{P}}\right)^{2C}\leq \tilde{C}\cdot r^{2C},
$$
where $\tilde{C}$ is another constant, not depending on $r$, and in fact, depending just of $C$.

My attempt has been the following:

Firstly, as $||x||_{2}\leq ||x-\xi||_{2}+||\xi||_{2}$, by the triangle inequality, we can see easily that $||x||_{2}\leq 2r$. So, we have that:
$$
\left(||x||_{2}^{\mathbb{P}}\right)^{2C}=\left(1+||x||_{2}^{2}\right)^{C}\leq (1+4r^{2})^{C}
$$
But I am stuck in here... I am not sure how (if it is even possible) can I bound $(1+4r^{2})^{C}$ by $\tilde{C}r^{2C}$, with $\tilde{C}$ not depending of $r$...

I appreciate any guidance. Thanks in advanced!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$(||x||_{2}^{\mathbb{P}})^{2C}\leq \tilde{C}\cdot r^{2C}$ cannot hold with $\overline C$ independent of $r$ because the left side is at least $1$ and right side tends to $0$ as $ r \to 0$.